# Unexpected list element termination(Sender/MalformedInput) Amazon mws ListOrders API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-mws

I am using Meteor to access Amazon mws API's and i am trying to access my Orders so i am trying to hit ListOrderAPI with following parameters:-

```
    app.getPendingOrdersAPI({'CreatedAfter':startDate,'MarketplaceId':'A21TJRUUN4KGV'},function(err,res){
        if(err){
          console.log("error is...");
          console.log(err);
        }
})
```

As you can seen i am passing createdAfter parameter and marketplaceId parameters both are required so i pass both of them . I am using Orders API version

> /Orders/2013-09-01
>   But as i try to get Orders its throw an error that is as follows:-

```
 <ErrorResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
I20160706-15:40:07.238(5.5)?   <Error>        
I20160706-15:40:07.238(5.5)?     <Type>Sender</Type>
I20160706-15:40:07.239(5.5)?     <Code>MalformedInput</Code>
I20160706-15:40:07.239(5.5)?     <Message>Unexpected list element termination</Message>
I20160706-15:40:07.239(5.5)?   </Error>       
I20160706-15:40:07.240(5.5)?   <RequestId>06d7977b-99be-4fe6-8e34-f2dbd6df9263</RequestId>
I20160706-15:40:07.240(5.5)? </ErrorResponse>
```

i.e **Unexpected list element termination(Sender/MalformedInput**
As i google this so i found same on amazon seller forums but there was they are discussing about the php code and as solution they said change

> rawurlencode($params$key));

to

> rawurlencode($params[$key]));

but i am running my project on Node.js (Meteor) so i am not able to figure it out. Please let me know when this error is comes and what is the main cause for this . I am missing some parameter or passing parameter as wrong please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Praveen I am not sure if you also need to specify CreatedBefore date

Comment: Im having the same problem, but I am using php and the answer you put in your question is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

Try to replace MarketplaceId with MarketplaceId.Id.1